# Datatable Reports

Tags: vb.net, reporting

New to reports here.  Using VB.NET, my application makes use of datatables it creates from a postgresql database.

These datatables are defined at runtime rather than design-time, and I would like some way of generating reports from these datatables at runtime as well.

Should I be trying to create the report template at design-time, and then "binding" a datatable to it at runtime?

Your clarification is much appreciated.

Joe

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the datatables follow the DAO format, and the report will be created by your own code, this can be a good approach.

However, as is always the case, it would be best to get at least some knowledge on the datatables, for security reasons alone. Watch out for errors following from malicious code/database entries.